# What is the proper way of saving an image in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image, save

In my system, there is a feature that will save the image of the item added, What I do is I will save the filename of the image into SQL server, and the image will be save into the one of the folder of asp.net

here us my code for saving the filename of the image in sql server:

```
INSERT INTO schemaImage.Image(image_name) VALUES ('image1.FileName')
```

here is my code for saving the image into the folder:

```
image1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + image1.FileName))
```

is it possible to save an image into the database?

What is more proper in saving an image here?

Comment: Yes you can save an image to the database. But then, every time an image is requested, your DB server has to work. What is ideal IMO is to save only the path to the image in the database. Let your web server (IIS/Apache) handle the reading of file from the file system and the delivery of images to the client.

Comment: I would recommend reading Microsoft's white paper on SQL Server's filestreaming (introduced in SQL Server 2008). The white paper has an extensive section titled Choices for BLOB Storage on considerations of where to store your file data. If you find that SQL Server's filestreaming is not the option you want then the rest of the white paper will be immaterial to you, I believe.

Comment: Link to white paper (find the Filestream Storage hyperlink on the page): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh461480.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the image to bytes to store it in the database. You can use `IO.File.ReadAllBytes()` for local files or `Net.WebClient.DownloadData()` for web files. The `IMAGE` data type is going away in SQL Server, so use `VARBINARY(MAX)` to store it.

#### Code:

```vb
Dim url As String = "http://example.com/image.png",
    file As String = "c:\image.png"

Using connection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("your connection string"),
    saveImage As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.saveImage", connection)

    connection.Open()
    saveImage.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

    'use only one of these
    saveImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imageData", New Net.WebClient().DownloadData(url)) 'get file from url
    'saveImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imageData", IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)) 'get file locally

    saveImage.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

#### Procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[saveImage] ( @imageData AS VARBINARY(MAX) )
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.myImage ( imageData ) VALUES ( @imageData )
```

#### Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myImage](
    [imageData] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: ok sir I wil try this one and tell you if it is working, thanks

Comment: I made some changes in the code and it is working, thank you sir :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible to save an image as a binary type in SQL Server.

   [Details:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260858%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
    http://www.asp.net-crawler.com/articles/ADO.Net/Storing-binary-blob-data-images-files-SQL-server-ADONet.aspx
2. The proper way of saving an image depends on your application's requirements: e.g
   If you will need to modify the pictures very often and they're large, it's more appropriate to save them in your file system as it's built to handle fragmentation better.
   [Even more details..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260858%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can store image data in SQL Server there are data types like varbinary and image to store image data. You may find detailed information about usage of those types at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). But all before that you MUST read [Storing images in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/what-about-storing-images-in-sql-server) to decide whether to store images on database.