# Best Practice For Saving Images in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, image

There are many times that I wanted to save an image to an SQL Server. I have read some practices for saving images :

1) upload and save image to server, save the path inside the table

2) save image as binary

3) save image as base64 string

4) using BLOB(i haven't researched how it works)

Do you know which "way" is faster when you request from server an image?
Do you know which "way" is better so as not to make SQL server slower?
Do you know any other "way" which is better from the above?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What about storing images in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/what-about-storing-images-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Lamak It's not just about Blob or Not Blob. I have searched stackoverflow before post. What I'm searching with that post is what deveopers' experience says!

Comment: And that link is more than just "Blob or Not to Blob". _It has an answer with lots of good points on them

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has done [some research](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525) on this topic and has concluded that it depends on the size of your image. If most of your images are < 256Kb, you should probably use VARBINARY. On the other hand, if they are above 1Mb, then you should use a FILESTREAM (which is usually stored on the filesystem outside the database file).

If your images are linked to other data, it's often useful to separate the records itself from the images into different tables (i.e. create an Images table) so that the table with the data remains small and easy to manipulate.

Comment: what about base64. Get the string , convert it to image or byte() in the client and use it?

Comment: It will take up more space (about 37% more). What would be the advantage?

Comment: Let;s say you have an image in SQL. The first time you download it to the client and you save it. The second time you check the CHECKSUM so as to see if the base64 has changed(easy with strings) if it has you delete the stored file and you download the new one. With FILESTREAM can you check that change?

Comment: Why not use timestamps? Then it is also easy to extend to things like the If-Modified-Since HTTP header.

Answer (score 3):

Pls note that there is no “best” way universally but only the one that suits your specific need the most.

“Do you know which "way" is faster when you request from server an image?” – in this case #1 because you essentially store image in the file system and only retrieve image path from database.

“Do you know which "way" is better so as not to make SQL server slower?” – again #1 because it has to deal with less data. It’s easier for SQL Server to retrieve varchar representing path where image is stored than to retrieve the image itself in whatever form.

No.1 is the simplest and probably easiest to setup but pls note that there are disadvantages:

- if some image is deleted from file system SQL Server doesn’t have a clue that this happened
- When you delete row from SQL Server you also need to delete image from file system (if you want to keep things clear ;))
- You also need to backup data from file system and not only SQL Server database