# How to save the picture to sql database (with entity framework)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, webcam

I want to save the picture selected in my project to the local SQL Server database; using a procedure

Whats will be the correct method using entity framework? (The table "user" contains id as `PK` and img as `picture`)

Comment: When you work with EF you will have a class for each table. Show that class definition too.

Comment: I would suggest taking a read at this stack overflow question explaining [best practices for saving images in a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199907/best-practice-for-saving-images-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL use the `varbinary` type  for storing the bytes of the image. In Entity Framework it'll be mapped to `byte[]`.

If you read the image from a file, then you can use the `File.ReadAllBytes` method to read all the bytes into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your image as a Base64String into database.show the model class defenition.Then i can help you to write the controller code.