# How to retrieve image stored in objectImage datatype in database back in asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How can I retrieve an image that is stored in `ObjectImage` datatype in database into and ASP page? I am unable to find an appropriate datatype in asp.net for it.

Comment: Do you want to show the image in your page or to send it directly to the client?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: yes, i want to display it on my web page.

Answer (score 0):

In code behind file, you should use `byte[]` array data type. And in web page use a `<img>` tag.

More info and complete how-to is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969875/1814343)