# MVC using EF to store any files in SQL sever [BLOB]

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, blob

How to use EF to Store/Retrieve any files in MVC 4. I need some detailed tutorials which explaining to upload files to SQL and download them using BLOB, EF in MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, there is no difference between storing/retrieving images and all other files from/to database.

To do this, change your table to have the following columns:

- FileContent - varbinary(max)
- FileMimeType - varchar(50)

You can store any type of file by these columns. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969875/1814343) to see a complete  example.