# saving an image object in sql server database from action method

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

```
   [HttpPost]
   public void Test(HttpPostedFileBase file)
   {
       UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

       byte[] image = new byte[file.ContentLength];

       file.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);

       CrimeReport i = new CrimeReport 

       { 
       ImageId=1, ImageName="Ali",ImageContent = image,
       Active=true
       };
       db.CrimeReports.Add(i);

       db.SaveChanges();
   }
```

I am getting an exception on db.CrimeReports.Add(i);

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: This exception says that you pushing wrong data to entity framework model, also you can get it if any of mandatory properties of CrimeReport is not filled. Try to set breakpoint on db.SaveChanges() and debug it. In exception details you should see more info.

Comment: is your foreign key relation is one to one relation ship? let you know  One-to-one foreign key associations are not supported in EF.

Comment: I have added all compulsory fields of table and this table has a primary key ImageId and the other table has a foreign key ImageId.

Comment: I store images in db like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17969875/1814343