# How to render remote images through controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

In my asp.net mvc3 project I have attachments section where user can upload his confidental images(scanned contracts), which i store on remote server. But when i render attachments i don't want to give full URI of image like

```
<img href="http://imageURI..." />.
```

I think i can render them trough controller action like

```
public ActionResult RenderImage
{
    return File(...);
}
```

but in method File I can't pass URI path.

Can anyone suggest me better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an ASP.Net MVC controller return an Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17969875/1814343

Comment: Or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image

Answer (score 0):

If the client browser is not IE8, just use Data URI Image. Check [this](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/mvc-data-uri-html-helper/61) out.

```
@Html.DrawImage("content/images/cat.jpg","funny cat")
```

**Output**

```
<img alt="funny cat" src="data:image/jgp:base64,________" />
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer?

Comment: Basically the idea is to transform your locally stored images into data-URI images. So that you don't have to expose the hotlinks of your images.

Comment: @KyawThurein - I think a 100MB data uri might be excessive