# Storing SMALL images in MySql database and why is it different for SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, image, blob, varbinary

I understand that the question of storing images in a MySql database has been asked many times before, but I haven't seen anything said about really small images (~1-10KB) or rather it's always generalized to images of any size, and that they should always be stored as a location on the file system. The reason I'm asking is because I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server) that for Sql Server, using varbinary is more efficient if the images are less than 256KB and for anything above 1MB, it should be stored on the file system. This may be true for Sql Server, but is it true for MySql? And if it is true for both, is there an equivalent to varbinary(MAX) since MAX doesn't seem to be an appropriate input for varbinary in MySql(Maybe BLOB, but I hear everyone condemning the use of BLOB for pretty much any reason...).

So to clear it up a bit:

1. Is it still better, in MySQL, to store images on the file system even if they are very small?
2. If yes, why is it NOT recommended to do this in SQL Server as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server) (Smaller images are more efficiently stored as varbinary)?
3. If no, what would be the equivalent to varbinary(MAX) to avoid an error in case my image is slightly above 8K?

I guess I'm really just stuck on the differences between MySQL and SQL Server when in comes to handling images and why recommended practices seem to be different for both.

Comment: They are different because they are not the same DBMS. There are a number of ways of handling images in sql server. I have a feeling this question will be closed because it is almost totally going to bring out opinions instead of facts.

Comment: Let's talk about your use-case. How many images do you expect to have a year?

Comment: @zedfoxus Each user of the application will own one image which will have to be requested upon each fresh load of the app and with each refresh of viewing other user's profiles. Essentially, even if our user count is high (high for me would be in the thousands range), each will only have 1 image (we may allow for more but not at the beginning).