# operator "&" is not defined for types "string" and "image"

Tags: sql, vb.net

Good day,

I want to store an image in a db, but I have not been able achieve it. I am getting error as `operator '&' is not defined for types 'string' and 'image'`.
Please help.

```
Function InsertTask(ByVal IdTask As Integer, ByVal NameImage As String, ByVal PImage As Image)
    Dim MessageExit As String = "Great, the picture is Saved"
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALBUMES(IDTASKD, NAMEIMG, P_IMAGE) VALUES('" & IdTask & "','" & NameImage & "','" & PImage & "')", conex)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageExit = ":( Error:" + ex.ToString
    End Try
    Return MessageExit
End Function
```

Comment: What is P_IMAGE data type set to in SQL? Also you don't need single quote around IDTask as it is an integer.

Comment: SQL data type is image for P_IMAGE

Comment: See... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server One of the comments here mentions that image is being phased out in the latest versions of SQL

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to use the Parameter to use `SqlDbType`, and also avoid SQL injections , like this :

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALBUMES(IDTASKD, NAMEIMG, P_IMAGE) " &
                       "VALUES(@IDTASKD,@NAMEIMG,@P_IMAGE)", conex)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDTASKD", SqlDbType.Int).Value = IdTask
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAMEIMG", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = NameImage
cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_IMAGE", SqlDbType.Image).Value = PImage
```