# SQL Server 2014, best column type to store icon files with size ~16 k

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL 2014, what would be the best column type to store icon files with max size 16 k?

I was thinking VARBINARY(17000) but I am guessing the VARBINARY(max) might be more efficient?

Comment: IMHO, FSO is far easier, but if you must VARBINARY(max) would be best, but also I would have them in a separate table to avoid performance hits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [Storing images in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server)

> There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called To Blob or
>   Not To Blob.
>
> Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and
>   analysis is this:
>
> if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database VARBINARY column is more efficient
>
> if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server
>   2008's FILESTREAM attribute, they're still under transactional control
>   and part of the database)

You should partition your Database so the image column resides in a separate file.

I also recommended to take look at nvarchar data type as well.

I suggest not go with VARBINARY(MAX), use calculated size like in your case 16KB or 16Kb and have some +/- tolerance.You should restrict icon size limit in your application logic.

[To BLOB or Not To BLOB: Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

Comment: You should include a reference to the paper in the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done. Though original answer has mentioned link in it.

Comment: How can you not use Varbinary(max) if you intend to store a file with 256KB? That is 262144 of bytes you intend to store as Varbinary which would exceed the 8000 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`VARBINARY(N)` is limited to N<=8000 so for 16K images, you'd have to go with `VARBINARY(MAX)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188362.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Given Sql2014 as the platform I suggest you look into File Tables.