# How to store images in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, image

I do know that there is a answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server)

But I want to know these:

1. I know how to save them programmatically, but I don't know what data type to save them? Could I still use `image` datatype when I have converted my images as image to 256KB? Or should I save them into filestream data type?
2. What kind of fragmentation is the document about? In my scenario, I have 2k+ employees and counting, so that means my application would get bigger over time, If I saved the images as image, and did not followed the rules as stated by the research paper, would my images lose their intact picture? (e.g a picture with blue background somehow changes its color maybe?)
3. Should I save it in the exact table of my employee details table? Or should I save it in a different table?
4. Sorry but I did not really understand the NTFS thing, is it the RAM of my computer? Or the RAM of my server? And I am using a file server as my database, should I still convert my images or should I go with using `image` data type without the conversion?

Comment: Save them as `VarBinary(MAX)`

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: And also: `FILESTREAM` is *not* a separate datatype - it's just an *attribute* that you can add to `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save files of any type in SQL Server then you should use the `varbinary` data type.  You would use `varbinary(max)` unless you know that the files will be small.  You can then convert your images to a `Byte` array and save that to the database.

You can enable the FILESTREAM option on your SQL Server instance these days and it will then store the data outside the main MDF file although that will be transparent to your code, so you keep using the same queries as you would otherwise.

Comment: Storage is cheap, it's non sense to not just make it a varbinary(max) type. Just my opinion...

Comment: whats the difference between varbinary and image data type? i am now converting my images to 256KB, should i still use varbinary?

Comment: The most significant difference between the two data types is that `image` is deprecated and `varbinary` is not.  Had you read the documentation for the `image` data type, you'd have seen that it instructs you to use `varbinary` instead.

Comment: So should i save the image together with my employee details table? or should i save it to another table?( e.g. emppic table)

Comment: There's no specific need to create a separate table just because you want to save the contents of some files.  Just treat it like any other data.  Put it in a separate table if there's a logical reason to do so, otherwise don't.  For instance, if you might want to be able to link the same document to multiple record then a separate table makes sense.