# Image from Access database to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, ms-access

I am writing code in C# and I am reading some values from an MS-ACCESS database file and transferring them to a SQL Server database. One column is of type "OLE Object" and contains an image. I get the byte array and store it to SQL server database but it seems that value is corrupt and it can't be rendered back into an image. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Is your SQL field VARBINARY? There are some recommendations here about when to store it in the database and when to use FILESTREAM instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to rendered back and check before to store in SQL Server? I think that you would do this first.  However, there is a tool called: SSMA Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA) which I think is more convenient that move one by one, there is an interesting link to use it.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/2011/03/06/access-to-sql-server-migration-understanding-data-type-conversions/

Comment: I had tried that but finally the problem was my method of showing the image on the webpage so everything is solved now