# Fetching or Storing Image files VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using VB.Net and developed a desktop based application.
I am using SQL SERVER as backend for Data Storage.
I want to store Images. Using filesystem is the best way to store Images.
But how can I fetch/Store Image if I am using SQL server in LAN.

Say I created User in my application.
User A has Image 1
User B has Image 2

If user B stores IMAGE in PC1 and Login from PC 2 how can I fetch Image in PC2 from PC1?

Options I searched :

1. Using file System(Share folder of the Image and store Address in Database).
2. Storing Image Data in SQL DATABASE.(Not So convenient way as I read on Internet)

I am using SQL Server in LAN via TCP connection. Is 2nd Option Good doing such thing?
I read the link [Storing images in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server/5613926) Found many useful article like storing image with size less then 255kb in SQL SERVER is good. But I had no restriction on Image Size.

What shall I do and any other recommendation on how to store/fetch Image data?

Comment: If you enable the FILESYSTEM feature in SQL Server then you can interact with the database as though it contains the images but SQL Server will actually store them in the machine's file system.

Comment: Sorry, FILESTREAM, not FILESYSTEM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

"Storing Image Data in SQL DATABASE" yes it is convenient if you convert the image to base64 string and convert it back to image when reading, just make sure you have your column big enough to store a big string..